# Azure WordPress Site offline but want the data

Tags: wordpress, azure, local, offline, restore

Few days ago i took my WordPress Site offline because the page was just for testing and I wanted to install WordPress locally. Now I installed WordPress local but i forgot to save the data from the Azure Wordpress Site. So my question: Is there any way to restore the data from my Azure Website and import them into my local Website? This would be so helpful.

Comment: If your local installation does not have any new data you can import the db from the server and replace it. Is this you want then let me know I will tell the steps needed for migration.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately, the offline site already has new data that I would not like to lose. However, I have tried to bring the offline page on the same level as the old website and I think it is okay now.

Comment: Ok, If there were more data what you can do is to write custom scipts to connect and fetch the data to your local website and insert posts using default WordPress functions so that you dont lose any data.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help:)